# Tunnel between machine and vps with port forwarding

Tags: linux, windows-10, vpn, port-forwarding, vps

I need to create a tunnel between a windows machine with gray ip over NAT and a linux server with white ip and forward all ports, including udp.
Scheme machine > server
i.e. the port is opened on the machine this port becomes available on the server
How can i do this?